# What common Math errors should I be aware of when using .NET on x32 and x64 platforms?

Tags: .net, math, clr, floating-point, largenumber

What should I keep in mind when performing calculations using .NET?

For example, I know a little about floating point errors, but am unfamilliar with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Lounge.aspx?msg=3652789#xx3652789xx) forum post on CodeProject.  What do I need to know to complete my knowledge of .NET-based math so that I can advise how to work with parameters and results of varying bit-sizes.

Comment: Divide 10 by 3 and wonder why aliens with 3 fingers are mystified about your observation that multiplying the result by 3 doesn't produce 10 again.  You think that's normal.  They don't.  Now use 2 fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that floating point stores binary fractions, i.e. your number will be represented with a summation series of 2^(-n) where n is any integer from 1 to (mantissa size) raised to some exponent N. Use `decimal` for financial calculations.

Also remember that 64-bit word read/writes on a 32-bit processor are not atomic and thus are not thread-safe. More generally, try your best to not expect that shared mutable state is always safe to read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that different numeric types have different ranges: take a look at the static `MinValue` and `MaxValue` properties.  If you exceed these ranges (by addition, multiplication or whatever) then the answers won't be what you think they should be.  (Numbers wrap around from the maximum back to the minimum.)